# Make IE a default browser using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I want to write SubRoutine in Excel to make IE a default browser using VBA.

I have to run .bat file that will open Intranet url with random token parameter (from .bat file) with default browser. Some users may have Chrome as default browser but I want them to temporarily change to IE as my another SubRoutine require IE as a browser. I can change it back to chrome using VBA code.

I know that I can use shell to open IE with specified URL (even Chrome is set as default browser), but, as you may see, it will not solve my problem.

I expect to see code look like this

`Set Shell = CreateObject("wscript.shell")
 Shell.Run ("iexplore.exe --make-default-browser")`

Comment: You can create an instance of IE using VBA and navigate to your URL.  No need to change the user's default browser.

Comment: Like I said, I don't know url beforehand. The bat file open default browser by itself with random url.

Comment: Where does the bat file come from?

Comment: I would kill the person who changed my default browser to IE even temporarily. A VBA script should never do that and you should re-think whether this is the right approach. You are on the wrong path my padawan.

Comment: My another subroutine objective is to pass complicated data from Excel to Intranet by exploiting getElement... method. To access Intranet, I need to run bat file created by IT department. This bat file basically connect with IT system which generate token and open Intranet via url with token parameter. I don't think I can capture that randomly generated url.

Comment: What does the bat file look like (suitably redacted of course) ?

Comment: Bat File retrieve user IP and call intranet.exe while passing user IP with it. intranet.exe register user IP to its server and allow session for this user IP a limited time to access INTRANET. intranet.exe then returns an action → open a default browser with a url with randomly generated token parameter.

Comment: Well, my user can access INTRANET by opening Bat file which is the way they always do when they want to access INTRANET. Assume that their default browser is Chrome. They can copy url with randomly generated token parameter from Chrome and open it in IE. Then my another Subroutine can recognise INTRANET in IE.